# Как вывести двумерный масив в php

Tags: php

Знаю как вывести одномерный масив:

```
foreach ($array as $value) {}
```

или

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {}
```

Но что делать в этом случае?

```
    $A = array(
    array(
        "name"=>"John Petronnichi Wales",
        "sex"=>"Male",
        "email"=>"john_males166@gmail.com"
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Michale Josef Tabson",
        "sex"=>"Male",
        "email"=>"michaleTobys@gmail.com"
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Moral Eris Brigs",
        "sex"=>"Female",
        "email"=>"Eris_Brigs089@nova.got.com"
    )
);
```

Comment: В цикле форич параметр $value будет массивом. Например, $value[‘name’]

Comment: Спасибо большое всем!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В PHP нет двумерных и многомерных массивов. Но в PHP элементами массива могут быть другие массивы.

Цикл `foreach` перебирает массив и возвращает элементы этого массива, т.к. у Вас эти элементы, в свою очередь, являются массивами, то ничто не мешает запустить по этим элементам еще один цикл `foreach`

```
foreach ($A as $sub_array) {
  foreach ($sub_array as $key => $value) {
    printf("Name: %s, Value: %s\n", $key, $value);
  }
}
```

ну или просто обратиться как к массиву

```
foreach ($A as $sub_array) {
  echo $sub_array['name'];
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое! Очень информативно и исчерпывающе.

Answer (score 1):

Кроме вложенных циклов можно воспользоваться функцией *`array_walk_recursive()`* Она обойдёт массив любой глубины:

```
$A = array(
    array(
        "name"=>"John Petronnichi Wales",
        "sex"=>"Male",
        "email"=>"john_males166@gmail.com"
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Michale Josef Tabson",
        "sex"=>"Male",
        "email"=>"michaleTobys@gmail.com"
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Moral Eris Brigs",
        "sex"=>"Female",
        "email"=>"Eris_Brigs089@nova.got.com"
    )
);

array_walk_recursive($A,function($v,$k){ echo "$v<br>"; });
```

Результат:

```
John Petronnichi Wales
Male
john_males166@gmail.com
Michale Josef Tabson
Male
michaleTobys@gmail.com
Moral Eris Brigs
Female
Eris_Brigs089@nova.got.com
```

Answer (score 1):

Вдобавок к остальным ответам:

```
<?php
    $A = array(
    array(
        "name"=>"John Petronnichi Wales",
        "sex"=>"Male",
        "email"=>"john_males166@gmail.com"
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Michale Josef Tabson",
        "sex"=>"Male",
        "email"=>"michaleTobys@gmail.com"
    ),
    array(
        "name"=>"Moral Eris Brigs",
        "sex"=>"Female",
        "email"=>"Eris_Brigs089@nova.got.com"
    )
);  


        foreach($A as $val){
            echo '<pre>';
            echo $val['email'].' '.$val['sex'].' '.$val['email'];
            echo '</pre>';

        }
        ?>
```